# How can I add a MultipleChoiceField field to ConfigForm (djconfig library)?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that I'm trying to add a MultipleChoiceField to.

```
class BasicConfigForm(ConfigForm):
    site_name = forms.CharField(initial="Spirit", label=_("site name"))
    site_description = forms.CharField(
        initial="", label=_("site description"), max_length=75, required=False)
    site_wiki = forms.URLField(
        initial="", label=_("Wiki link"), required=False,
        widget=forms.URLInput(),
        help_text=(
            "Insert wiki link here"))
    bug_report_url = forms.URLField(
        initial="", label=_("Your bug report link"), required=False,
        widget=forms.URLInput(),
        help_text=(
            "Insert bug report link here (don't post anything if there is no link.)"))
    enabled_languages = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label='Enabled Languages',
        choices=base.LANGUAGES,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False,
    )
    comments_per_page = forms.IntegerField(
        initial=20, label=_("comments per page"), min_value=1, max_value=100)
    topics_per_page = forms.IntegerField(
        initial=20, label=_("topics per page"), min_value=1, max_value=100)
```

This field appears and displays fine, but when I try to save this form, everything except this field is saved. How can I make sure it is saved?

my views:

```
User = get_user_model()


@administrator_required
def config_basic(request):
    form = BasicConfigForm(data=post_data(request))
    if is_post(request) and form.is_valid():
        enabled_languages = form.cleaned_data['enabled_languages']
        form.enabled_languages = enabled_languages
        form.save()
        messages.info(request, _("Settings updated!"))
        return safe_redirect(request, "next", request.get_full_path())
    print()
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name='spirit/admin/config_basic.html',
        context={'form': form})
```

I tried to override save() in BasicConfigForm, but I think I did it wrong.

```
    def save_enabled_languages(self):
        self.enabled_languages = self.cleaned_data['enabled_languages']

    def save(self):
        self.save_enabled_languages()
        super(BasicConfigForm, self).save()
```